# Silencing or pausing Windows media when Android Google Assistant is triggered

Tags: windows, android, media, speech-recognition

I hope this this in scope, as the rules ban questions related to "cell phones or smart phones, **except insofar as they interface with your computer**"

On Android, media is silenced when Google Assistant is triggered, while it listens for a command

How can I make it so that Windows (and ideally Linux, but Windows is the prime target for now) media is likewise silenced when that's triggered, so I can give a command to my phone next to my computer w/o the media obscuring my voice, and then the media will resume playing after Google Assistant finishes its action?

Comment: So, the question is basically "how do I voice control my computer to mute for a certain number of seconds when I say a specific verbal passphrase?" Have you looked into voice controlling your computer and the commands you could do with that?

Comment: No, that's not the question. I'm trying to get it so the computer responds to Google Assistant activity, and pauses media when Google Assistant is running on my phone.

Comment: Are you sure? I mean, it's possible, but it may be simpler to get the computer to listen too. But, that said, if you want the phone to tell the PC to mute, that's a pretty well defined series of tasks. You need a system on the phone to recognize that state and send a signal through some service or system that the computer can understand and then take action in response to. So, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I guess the problem is that I don't think a PC can detect Google Assistant activity on a mobile phone out of the box, even if it's on the same Google account, because there's simply no connection between them.